# How do I texture paint model?

Tags: texture-painting

I went through many tutorials and documentation but cannot seem to get it to work. Bug? I go to texture paint, I add new image, set color size. In model, I select single image, selext the image I created, object becomes color. Able to use fill to change entire color, but none of the other brush options work and cannot draw on object in 3d mode or uv editor. Am I missing a step?

Comment: Is this with every object you try in new files, or just this one with this file? Does it happen still when appending the object to a new file? Does it still have a problem if you have saved the image to disk directory?

Comment: Plz check if you have "Texture" or "Texture Mask" loaded(under TexDraw brush settings ).If yes ,cancel and try again.

Comment: Did you unwrap the object in edit mode?